# Push key values to the json object and pass it in ajax request

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have a form submit using ajax and vanilla javascript as below. what i am trying to achieve is to save all the selected values to ***items*** which is working fine.

Now i need to push these values with their keys to the object ***obj*** which will create the object as below and the pass it in my xhttp.send();

```
var obj={"language":"English";
         "location":"USA";
         "function":"production"
        }
```

**JS Code**

```
        saveUserSetting.addEventListener('click', function () {            
            var links = document.querySelectorAll('.main-content .dropdown > a');
            for (var i = 0; i <= links.length; i++) {
                var obj = {};
                var items = links[i].textContent;
                console.log(items); // Items will have the values now English, USA, Production. i want to push this values to
            }
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.open("POST", "data.json", true);
            xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    // response
                }
            };
            xhttp.send("location=USA&langugage=English&function=production");
        });
```

I am using plain javascript. no jquery or any other framework. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly, you are able to generate the array:

```
['English', 'USA', 'Production']
```

Then one way to get the result you want, is to replace your `for` loop with this:

```
var labels = ['language', 'location', 'function']
var obj = links.reduce((output, item, index) => {
  output[labels[index]] = item
}, {})
```

This just uses `reduce` to perform the array to object conversion with labels.